# How to have label text change to message after user types in textfield?

Tags: swift, xcode

So I am very very new to coding in general and I am taking a class learning about creating apps in xcode. We were assigned to make our first app from scratch. My idea was to make a guessing game where the user is given a picture up close, and they are have to guess what it is. I want it where there's a label, textfield and button. They type their guess in the textfield, click the button to check their answer, and then the label text changes saying "you are wrong" or you are correct". I've looked all over and haven't found much on how to change a label's text depending on what is entered in the textfield. I assumed that I would use an if-else statement but it seems like that is only for integers. Any help on what to do? I've connected everything also. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: We are not here to do your homework. What have you done so far? What part exactly do you need help with? Update your question with some relevant code and clearly explain what you need help with. Your current question is far too broad. And, FYI, an `if` statement can be used to compare two strings. It's not just for integers.

Comment: I never asked you to do my homework, if I was, I would have told you to make the entire app for me. Just giving you some background information on my situation. My question says exactly what I need help with, I want to learn how to change a label's text to a message depending on what the user enters in the textfield.

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController{



    var dictionaryForQuestionAndAnswer  = ["what is the best way to learn coding?":"trying","who is best person to ask question?":"Google"]

    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    var answerIndex = 0
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        questionLabel.text = ""


    }



    @IBAction func questionClicked(_ sender: Any) {

        let random  = randomInt(min: 1, max: 2)

        if(random == 1)
        {
            answerIndex = 1
           questionLabel.text = "what is the best way to learn coding?"
        }
        else
        {
            answerIndex = 2

            questionLabel.text = "who is best person to ask question?"

        }
    }

    @IBAction func answerClicked(_ sender: Any) {

        if let answer = textField.text
        {
            if( answerIndex == 1 && answer == dictionaryForQuestionAndAnswer["what is the best way to learn coding?"])
            {
                questionLabel.text = "You are correct"
            }
            else if( answerIndex == 2 && answer == dictionaryForQuestionAndAnswer["who is best person to ask question?"])
            {
                questionLabel.text = "You are correct"
            }

            else
            {
                questionLabel.text = "You are wrong"
            }


        }
    }

    func randomInt(min: Int, max:Int) -> Int {
        return min + Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(max - min + 1)))
    }




    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks! So if I just wanted to do one question, would I just delete the second part of the if statement that you had?

Comment: if you just want to do one question just insert one question inside the dictionary     var dictionaryForQuestionAndAnswer  = ["what is the best way to learn coding?":"trying"]. It will always show you one question then. If you think this answer helped you, please take a moment to accept answer?

Comment: I thought it did help at first but I tried the code and there were a lot of erors

Comment: You will still have to create your own UI and link the UI components like button texfield label etc to my code. SO is not the place to simply copy paste the code and expect it to be submitted as your homework.

Comment: Go through this first : http://codewithchris.com/xcode-tutorial-user-interaction/